# How to fix conflicting packages in blackarch

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

According to BlackArch offical website this is out you update the system `pacman -Syu --needed --overwrite='*' blackarch` but when I run this command on a newly created vm I get the following error

```
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: removing 'python-mistune' from target list because it conflicts with 'python-mistune1'
:: python-mistune1 and python-mistune are in conflict. Remove python-mistune? [y/N] 
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: python-mistune1 and python-mistune are in conflict
```

I tried to update archlinux-keyring using `pacman -S archlinux-keyring` but this did not solve the problem

I understand that the error is about python2 and python3 version but my goal is to fix this error without totally removing python2/3